# How to show/hide item in listview..

Tags: android, listview, hide, visibility, show

I have a `list view`, and one of its items I set `android: visibility ="gone "`.
I want when I click an item from the `ListView`, I hide the item becomes visible, and if the item had already seen, when I click the `ListView` return, the item was going to hide anymore.

Comment: How can you click an item if it's gone in the first place? Or is it a different item?

Answer (score 2):

To get a helpful answer to your question you might want to put some more effort into phrasing it. I'm not quiet sure what you are trying to do but I hope the following helps:

You can get an items visibility by calling

```
View.getVisibility();
```

and then compare it to

```
View.INVISIBLE or View.VISIBLE
```

and then setting the visibility according to your needs with

```
View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```